# Angular: Create subscription on onChange of a select element

Tags: angular, typescript

I've this html:

```
<select id="appFilter" name="appFilter"...
```

I'd like to get a reference to this in order to create a subscription to `onChange` observable.

```
@ViewVhild("appFilter")
private appFilterSelect: ??????;
```

I was looking on picking it up using `ViewChild` annotation, but I'd like to get access to `onChange` observable.

I know I'm able to do it like this `(change) = "handler"` in the template , but I need to subscribe to change event from the component class not in the template .

Any ideas  ?

Comment: `(change)="handler($event)"`

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mpsesl

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like this :

```
@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: [ './app.component.css' ]
})
export class AppComponent  {
  @ViewChild('toto', {static: true}) mySelect: ElementRef;

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.mySelect.nativeElement.addEventListener('change', (val) => {
      console.log(val.target.value);
    });
  }
}
```

But first, you need to mark your html element :

```
<select #toto>
  <option>Banana</option>
  <option>Akouna</option>
</select>
```

Here is the [stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-stack-1)